# Create new column that calculate percentage repeat N times

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to know how to calculate the percentage of these columns and save it in a new column next to it for N times.
Example

```
d1 = [['0.00', '10','11','15'], ['2.99', '30','40','0'], ['4.99', '5','0','2']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1, columns = ['Price', '1','2','3'])
```

I want the following operation iterates through all the columns (besides Price of course)

```
df1['1%'] = df1['1'] / df1['1'].sum() (I got an error when I tried this)
```

Result:

```
d2 = [['0.00', '10','0.22','11','0.2156','15','0.8823'], ['2.99', '30','0.66','40','0.7843','0','0'], ['4.99', '5','0.11','0','0','2','0.1176']]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2, columns = ['Price', '1','1%','2','2%','3','3%'])
```

(The columns can be N times so I need to iterate through all the columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need:

```
m=df1.set_index('Price').div(df1.set_index('Price').sum()).add_suffix('%')
df2=pd.concat([df1.set_index('Price'),m],axis=1).sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
```

---

```
   Price   1        1%   2        2%   3        3%
0   0.00  10  0.222222  11  0.215686  15  0.882353
1   2.99  30  0.666667  40  0.784314   0  0.000000
2   4.99   5  0.111111   0  0.000000   2  0.117647
```

Note: this is assuming the dtypes are:

```
df1.dtypes
Price    float64
1          int32
2          int32
3          int32
```

Comment: @Seph77 if any of the answers posted helped you, please consider marking that answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to let users know that that solution works TIA :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the Output, you need to convert string to numeric using [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)

```
pd.concat([df1, df1.drop('Price',1).apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x).div(pd.to_numeric(x).sum()))
               .rename(columns=lambda x: x+'%')], 1)
```

Output:

```
    Price   1   2   3   1%                2%          3%
0   0.00    10  11  15  0.222222    0.215686    0.882353
1   2.99    30  40  0   0.666667    0.784314    0.000000
2   4.99    5   0   2   0.111111    0.000000    0.117647
```

Comment: Thanks!  but do you know how I can iterate that formula through all the columns? That's the part that I struggle the most

Comment: @Seph77 Feel free to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=df1.columns[1:]
df1[a+'%'] = df1[a].astype(float) / df1[a].astype(float).sum()
```

*output*

```
Price   1   2   3   1%           2%         3%
0.00    10  11  15  0.222222    0.215686    0.882353
2.99    30  40  0   0.666667    0.784314    0.000000
4.99    5   0   2   0.111111    0.000000    0.117647
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down your question into 2 parts:

**1) Why you get an error when you try to calculate the percentage for each column:**

Basically, your columns are string types. You can either transform your column into a float type or change the type when defining your dataframe:

- Changing the type of a column: `df1['1%'] = df1['1%].astype(float)`
- Changing the type when defining your dataframe:

`d1 = [[0.00, 10, 11, 15], [ 2.99, 30, 40, 0], [ 4.99, 5, 0, 2]]`

**2) Iterate the formula through all the columns:**

The following code iterate your formula and create another column in the original dataframe:

```
for column in df1.drop(['Price'], axis=1).columns:
    df1[column + '%'] = df1[column] / df1[column].sum()
```